# How to translate "Cahiers individualistes"?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

The journal *Action* (page in question found [here](https://dada.lib.uiowa.edu/files/show/4077) from The International Dada Archive) is described using the phrase

> Cahiers individualistes de philosophie et d'art

I've translated this literally as "Individualist notebooks on philosophy and art", but does "Cahiers individualistes" have another, non-literal, translation?

Comment: We're not supposed to do into English here in answers but I think that's fine as you did it. I have translated tons of French intellectual stuff into English and there is rarely a consensus though here I can't see anything else that would work. There are other famous notebooks like Gramsci's Prison Notebooks. Usually, notebooks are from one person but not in this case. :)

Comment: Here ***cahiers*** describes a stitched paperback, a booklet as opposed to a hard bound book. No notes were written on these *cahiers*, so maybe "notebook" isn't the best translation. ***Individualistes*** is an adjective so "individualistic" might be less ambiguous than "individualist" that might be more often a noun than an adjective.

Comment: Here *cahier* is a synonym of "revue". It is one of the usage of the word [(TLF C2 b)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cahier), lots of literary & art journals are called *cahiers*.  If I had to translate it here I'd use the same word as when translating *revue*, i.e.  "journal".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it is written the question is about finding the right phrase in English, which is [not on topic](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on French Language.

Comment: cahiers here is **not a literal notebook**. It means a collection of writings. Those are called notebooks in English: Gramsci's Prison Notebooks. In English, a journal is a diary and is typically written in a notebook. The Poetry Notebooks of Ralph Waldo Emerson. Publishers typically take actual notebooks and republish them as books but keep the original word notebook used by an author. That is the idea here, too. Typically, they are not "formal" writings.

Comment: The most famous cahiers of all are probably, **Les cahiers du cinéma** which by the way is not usually translated. Titles of journals (as in academic journals) are not usually translated but left as is.

Comment: @Lambie.  I'm amazed you say a journal is a diary, I expect excerpts of a diary could be published in a journal, for literary criticism or such but saying "a journal is a diary and typically written in a notebook" is news to me. I've got lots of journals at my side, in English as well as In French, and none are written in "notebooks" (a notebook one can "write in" is a piece of stationery, not a notebook like in "Gramsci's Prison Notebooks").  The usual word for "journal" in French is *revue* or *cahiers*, the word *cahier* being only used for literary & art publishings.

Comment: @None: I keep a notebook of my thoughts. I keep a diary of my thoughts. I keep a journal of my thoughts. Bonnet blanc, blanc bonnet. Les trois mots. COMPARE:  Academic journals (The Annals of Internal Medicine) is a different meaning of the word journal. All these hard-back books such as Gramsci's prison notebooks mean the publishers took the guy's notebooks and published them as a book. I really do not need English lessons. Thank you, though.

Comment: cahiers can also be translated as "review" as in The New York Review of Book. Les Cahiers du Cinéma = Film Reviews, even though of course one simply does not translate these **titles***.

Comment: @None "I'm amazed you say a journal is a diary," journal has two distinct meanings in English.